# Finding all possible Acronyms

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I have creating a script using VBA to go through a Word document to find all word that could possibly be an acronym but I found that my regEx pattern is not find all of them.

The regEx pattern I am using is "([A-Z]{2,})(-*([A-Z]{2,})*[A-Za-z0-9]*)*"

With this pattern I am able to find

```
AA
AAA
AA-BB
AA-BBB
AAA-BB
AAA-BBB
AAA-1234
AAA-BBB-1234
```

but it does not find these words

```
B2B
B2B-1234
B2B-A1A-1234
```

The expectation of the word match should be that the first character is a letter and must contains at least two uppercase letters and at least one number. In addition, if there are dashes in the the word then the characters before the dash must match the expectation of the word match.

Is there is a way to use the regEx pattern above to also include the letter-digit-letter acronyms too?

Comment: I don't think [acronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym) means what you think it means.

Comment: What acronyms do not mean an abbreviation formed from the initial letters of other words and pronounced as a word (e.g. ASCII, NASA ). If that is not the case then what do you can NASA, P2W, PVP?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by acronym, since the only definition you're providing is the regex itself, which you're trying to fix - so it clearly isn't the correct definition. Would `12AB` be an 'acronym'? How about `AA-BB-12`? Can you provide a better definition or description?

Comment: Grismar, I see your point and should have been more clear on what the expectation constitutes to be an acronym. I have updated the post but the expectation of the word match should be that the first character is a letter and must contains at least two uppercase letters and at least one number. In addition, if there are dashes in the the word then the characters before the dash must match the expectation of the word match. So 12AB will not be an acronym but AB-12AB or AB-1233-12 will be. I hope that clears it up.

Comment: @Milco, what is the language you are trying to match in?

Comment: @entpnerd The language the script is currently written in is VBA.

Comment: @Milco You may be interested in: https://forums.windowssecrets.com/showthread.php/175457-Count-occurrences-of-word?p=1052437&viewfull=1#post1052437

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Milco, welcome to StackOverflow. I think that the following regex will work for you:

```
([A-Z][A-Z0-9]+)(-[A-Z0-9]{2,})*
```

This regex accommodates digits and an optional number of hyphenated terms and matches each of your cases above. I tested it out at [regextesteronline.com](https://www.myregextester.com/index.php#highlighttab) - I'm assuming that VB.net regexes are the same as VBA, which they should be, at least for basic regexes.